# Unable to bind ID Property to the View,due to conflict with ID Property of System.Web.UI.Page in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, view

While debugging into view i did a quick watch and i found that for "ID" its showing a GUID  due to that i had to change the name of the property in my model as i had property by the name ID, i had problems when binding the value from the session to the textbox.

Is there any other way besides changing the name of the property?

Comment: add this snippet in ur view <%=ID%> and check it out it will display a GUID value on ur page.

Comment: If ID is GUID it is normal it displays on page. Really, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Its some asp.net thing. I've never seen it before.

Comment: no prob on Model.ID but just ID returns the GUID

Comment: Please rephrase the question. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: What is the ID property ? If your trying to access your model , then you use what mathieu suggested. - The ID property.. is some property of the page, you don't use that.